# RunTime Error 13, Type Mismatch MsgBox Cancel

Tags: vba, excel

Getting a Run-Time Error 13 type mistmatch error when clicking cancel on a message box.

I tried making the following script to handle if a message box is empty, however upon bug checking, clicking cancel on the message box throws it all out.

Any ideas?

```
Private Sub ChangeDebtAmounts_Click()

Dim Debt1 As Integer, Debt2 As Integer, Debt3 As Integer, Debt4 As Integer
Dim D1Range As String, D2Range As String, D3Range As String, D4Range As String

D1Range = ActiveSheet.Range("Y15")
D2Range = ActiveSheet.Range("Y16")
D3Range = ActiveSheet.Range("Y17")
D4Range = ActiveSheet.Range("Y18")


Debt1 = InputBox("Please Enter in the account limit for " & D1Range)
If Debt1 = "" Then
  MsgBox ("Setting " & D1Range & " to Zero, No Value Entered")
Else
Range("AA15").Value = Debt1 - Range("S58")
End If

End

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type mismatch is with the `InputBox` rather than the `MsgBox`. To fix it, it is enough to change `Dim Debt1 As Integer` to `Dim Debt1 As Variant`. Also, you are using `MsgBox` as a sub rather than a function so the correct syntax should be

```
MsgBox "Setting " & D1Range & " to Zero, No Value Entered"
```

rather than

```
MsgBox ("Setting " & D1Range & " to Zero, No Value Entered")
```

In this case the parentheses are harmless, but if you try to give additional arguments to `MsgBox` while using it as a sub then you will get a syntax error.

Comment: @John - If a VBA function is being called by name, there is no need for brackets. In the case of `MsgBox`, this would be any time there's only one button (ie, `[OK]`). I used to be picky about that too but there is no advantage. Therefore even `MsgBox D1Range` is valid in this case; another example being `Shell "calc"` if you don't require confirmation that the calculator has opened.  See: [What are the rules governing usage of brackets in VBA function calls?](//stackoverflow.com/a/5413977/8112776)

Comment: @ashleedawg For the first year or so when I was doing VBA I always used `MsgBox(msg)` with no problem at all. Then one day I tried to add a title to the message and was flabbergasted by the resulting syntax error (even posting a message to the main Excel VBA programming Usenet group in those pre-Stack Overflow days). I wanted to put in a little warning in case OP wasn't aware of the subtle distinction so as to spare them the pain I went through when I learned it the hard way.

Comment: @JohnColeman - I, too, am from the Usenet era. My first forum was long before VBA, connecting to BBS's via 300-baud acoustic coupler on Radio Shack computers..(There are a couple flashbacks for you on my [profile](//stackoverflow.com/users/8112776?tab=profile))...  Anyhow, like so many things in VBA I think the syntax for functions is a case of personal preference.  There are certain counter-intuitive rules (if using `Call` you have to use the brackets, but otherwise they're optional) but I haven't had a problem.  IMHO, at the end of the day, the right way is "whatever gets the job done!"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different take on your question.  See my comments within the code.

(It's longer just because of the comments; optionally, you can remove any lines of comments, as well as any other blank lines.)

```
Private Sub ChangeDebtAmounts_Click()

    Dim Debt1, Debt2, Debt3, Debt4 'data type "Variant" is assumed
    Dim D1Range As String,D2Range As String,D3Range As String,D4Range As String

    'by using a "With" statement, you can use "." instead of "ActiveSheet."
    With ActiveSheet

        D1Range = .Range("Y15")
        D2Range = .Range("Y16")
        D3Range = .Range("Y17")
        D4Range = .Range("Y18")

        'I added a title to the dialog and a default value of zero
        Debt1=InputBox("Enter the account limit for " & D1Range, "Limit?" ,0)

        'Check user response:
        If Debt1 = "" Or Debt1 = 0 Then

            'User clicked cancel or entered zero.
            MsgBox "Setting " & D1Range & " to Zero, No Value Entered"

            'I assume your next step is to set the input value to zero:
            Debt1  = 0
        Else
            'you don't need to specify ".Value" in most cases (it's assumed)
            'also:by using the "." we're referring to ActiveSheet again.
            .Range("AA15") = Debt1 - .Range("S58")

        End If

    End With '(the end of "With ActiveSheet")

End Sub
```

A couple other thoughts:

- it appears like you're going to use different variables for each `InputBox` but this is not necessary: you can re-use the same variable in this case, without issue.
- `ActiveSheet` just refers to "whichever worksheet (tab) happens to be open when the code is run".  It's a good idea to explicitly refer to a specific worksheet, to prevent potential problems in the future.

  For example if your cells such as `Y15` are on worksheet `Sheet1`, you could replace `ActiveSheet` with `Sheets("Sheet1")`.

---

### Alternate method (loop through all 4 cells)

These methods are for demonstration only - if you already have your solution figured out, stick with that, there's no point in wasting time! These are just to show other ways to do the same thing.

Just for fun, here's another alternate method, that loops through all 4 cells `Y15:Y18` and repeats the same `MsgBox`'s.

I wasn't sure what happens with the other 3 values the user enters, so I left those blank.

```
Private Sub demo_Alternate()
  Dim userInput As Variant, arr As Variant, myCell
  With Sheets("Sheet1") '<<<<<< change this to actual worksheet name
      arr = .Range("Y15:Y18") ' arr(1) to arr(4) are now cell references
      For Each myCell In arr
          userInput = InputBox("Enter account limit for " & myCell, "Limit?", 0)
          If userInput = "" Or userInput = 0 Then 'Cancelled or 0 entered
              MsgBox "Setting " & myCell & " to Zero, No Value Entered"
              userInput = 0
          Else
              Select Case Split(myCell.Address, "$")(2)
                  Case 15 'do what you need to for cell Y15
                      Range("AA15") = userInput - Range("S58")
                  Case 16
                      'do what you need to for cell Y16
                  Case 17
                      'do what you need to for cell Y16
                  Case 18
                      'do what you need to for cell Y16
              End Select
          End If
      Next myCell 'loop to next cell
  End With
End Sub
```

---

**OR,** if all four cells are getting from `S58` and put into column `AA` of the same row, like:

```
...if your end-goal is the pattern:
AA15 = {Y15 or UserEntry} - S58
AA16 = {Y16 or UserEntry} - S58
AA17 = {Y17 or UserEntry} - S58
AA18 = {Y18 or UserEntry} - S58
```

...then something like this could work (and is even more compact).

```
Private Sub demo_Alternate2()
    Dim userInput As Variant, arr As Variant, myCell, rowNum As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1") '<<<<<<<<<<<<< change this to actual worksheet name
        arr = .Range("Y15:Y18") ' arr(1) to arr(4) are now cell references
        For Each myCell In arr
            userInput = InputBox("Enter account limit for " & myCell, "Limit?", 0)
            If userInput = "" Or userInput = 0 Then 'Cancelled or 0 entered
                MsgBox "Setting " & myCell & " to Zero, No Value Entered"
            Else
                rowNum = Split(myCell.Address, "$")(2)
                Range("AA" & rowNum) = userInput - Range("S58")
            End If
        Next myCell
    End With
End Sub
```

One noteworthy technique used here is the use of an array (`arr`) to read multiple cell values at once instead of a separate line for each cell input.

```
arr = .Range("Y15:Y18")
```

...assigns the four cells to the array so you can refer to the array as if:

```
arr(1) = Y15
arr(2) = Y16
arr(3) = Y17
arr(4) = Y18
```